# unwind segue taking forever to unwind

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

Here's my situation.

I have three view controllers, Root, Pushed and Leaf.

Root is the lowest on the stack. "Pushed" got pushed by a push segue. "Leaf" was put on the stack by a modal segue.

Root has these routines:

```
-(IBAction) specialSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue {
 // Do stuff.
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}
```

From "Leaf", I'm calling an unwind segue that will trigger "specialSegue". This all works.

What is totally weird, is that seconds can go by before "viewWillAppear" gets called. I'm staring at the screen, and waiting for it to unwind. I know that "specialSegue" got called, b/c of my logs. It gets called immediately. But the actual unwinding can happen much later. Sometimes, if I tap the screen again, in a place that isn't even a button, then the views unroll and viewWillAppear gets hit.

I guess that's it. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the unwind segue? Odd delays in UI execution normally happen when you call UIKit methods from non-main threads.

Comment: The unwind segue is called as a direct response from a button press. So this action is happening in the main thread.

Comment: @jrturton beat me to it. Check your threading/GDC code, these kind of issues are usually generated by that mistake.

Comment: OK, what stuff happens in specialSegue? What happens when you pause the app while you're waiting for the transform to happen - what's the backtrace look like?

Comment: Nothing happens. I'm setting an NSString property. It does that just fine and the segue processing is over. Then I wait and wait until, eventually, the "viewWillAppear" call gets hit.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks jrturton and Bruno. I can't explain it, and I promise you that if I set a breakpoint, the debugger says that I'm calling "performSegue..." from the main thread. But if I wrap the call up like this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:[self.segues objectAtIndex:row] sender:nil];
    });
```

It works great. It really looks like I'm in the main thread here, so the above code shouldn't be needed. But it does solve my problem. So I'm moving on.